# preg_match_all doesn't match when using a carat (^)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm using `preg_match_all` to find a URL in a HTML file. The URL always appears at the start of the line, with no leading space, like this:

```
<A HREF="/link/to/here"><strong>Next</strong></A>
```

I used this to match it:

```
preg_match_all('|^<A HREF="(?<url>.*?)"><strong>Next</strong>|', $html, $url_matches);
```

It didn't work until I removed the carat (^) character. I thought that the carat matched the start of a line. Why is it causing my match to fail?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there's no whitespace at the beginning of your string? What happens if you run it through `trim()`, and then send the resulting trimmed string through your `preg_match_all()` that has the caret?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the `m` modifier:

```
preg_match_all('|^<A HREF="(?<url>.*?)"><strong>Next</strong>|m', $html, $url_matches);
```

then `^` matches at start of a line, else it would only match at the start of the entire string.

More Info: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 3):

`^` matches *start-of-string* not *start-of-line*. Use the `m` ("multi-line") modifier: `//m`